# "Decorate" several classes with a specific method in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns

I'm not yet that into design patterns so "Sorry!" to bother you with such a question, that might be obvious.

The thing is, I have several classes: `Show`, `Segment`, `Command`. These three classes are totally different, except the one thing: They all have an `NSArray` called `schedules`, which contains `ScheduleItem` classes.

In my workflow I need to check, if the current time matches a scheduleItem to set the `Show`,`Segment` or `Command` active. So, I'd like to have a method on all these three classes called `isActive()`. Since this method does the same for all current and future classes, I'm looking for a way to implement the `isActive` method just once, and reuse it in those classes.

Is there a nice way doing this?

To remember, those classes have absolutely nothing in common, except the schedules array. So, I'd like to avoid subclassing. But you can convince me otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create smth like this

```
@interface ScheduleCollection : NSObject {
    NSArray* schedules;
}

@property NSArray* schedules;

/**
  Return true if matches.
*/
-(BOOL) match:(ScheduleSclass); //or call it isActive or whatever you like 

@end
```

Then replace schedules array in Show, Segment, Command with ivar of this class. If you need to compare time just get the property and call match:

```
Show* show = ...;

BOOL m = [show.schedules match: my_time];
```

Answer (score 1):

There's really no design pattern for this except generic inheritance (shared base class with the method). You can't add it as a category for all three, as they don't share a base class.

If you want to avoid introducing a base class, you can use the fact that type id is a typeless object, and you can invoke any method on it at runtime. Only it will fail if the actual objec doesn't have the method...

On each of the objects, create a method called getSchedule like this:

```
- (NSArray*) getSchedule {
  return schedule;
}
```

Then just create this method somewhere else

```
-(BOOL) isActive:(id)anyObjectWithGetScheduleAnyOtherWillFailWithSelectorNotImplemented
{
  // You could do an explicit check to determine if the object passed in implements
  // getSchedule, but I skipped it here.
  NSArray* schedule =  [anyObjectWithGetScheduleAnyOtherWillFailWithSelectorNotImplemented getSchedule];
  <your implementation here>
}
```

In my opinion, you would be better off just introducing a shared base class, as it's a lot clearer and won't really take that much more work. But if you have good reasons not to, this will also do the job.

Comment: Sry, I also like your approach, but the other one worked better for me.

Comment: Well that's OK. You should always pick the solution that works best for you :) What he did was clever: Instead of introducing a hack or a common base class for your objects, he introduced a common base class for the NSArray - I like it!